In chip manufacturing process descriptions like "7 nm", "5 nm" - what is being measured?
I'm a software rather than a hardware person and have a newbie terminology question: When chip manufacturers or tech reporters describe advances in chip making technology, they typically talk about manufacturing "process nodes", and refer to these nodes using a length: "10 nm", "5 nm", "4 nm" etc. Naturally, as these lengths decrease, the artifacts produced with litography (or whatever) on the chips are smaller. But - what do these figures mean, literally? i.e. what baseline length or distance decreases from 10 to 5 to 4 nanometers?

Often the space between traces.

if you wrote your name on the chip, then that would be the smallest possible dot on the letter i

@SolarMike: But if this is not standardized, then anyone can fiddle with their equipment a little (well, maybe) to artificially create super-small artifacts - just to prove the point, while actually printing the chip with artifacts at a lower resolution.
